# Javascript request with httr

Tags: javascript, html, json, r, rest

I am trying to automate submission via Javascript form.

The data can be requested here: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/next-web/cart.html

```
URL='http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/next-web/rest/orders'
body=list(email=REQUEST.EMAIL,items=list(list(dataset='DMSP',satellite='F15',orbitStartTime='2012-01-01',orbitEndTime='2012-01-05',geometry='')))

r=POST(URL,body=body,encode = "form", verbose())
```

The response is that at least one item and email must be provided. As if no information was provided to REST.

I have traced via Google Chrome dev tools. The "body" follows the format of the REQUEST payload. Here's other information when I submit via the form. I'd be OK to move away from R. Just don't know what I'm doing. Any help would be great!

```
**Request headers**
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:154
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:_gat_GSA_ENOR0=1; _ga=GA1.3.1106617633.1453162177; _gat_GSA_ENOR1=1
Host:www.ngdc.noaa.gov
Origin:http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov
Referer:http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/next-web/cart.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

**Response headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov
Connection:close
Content-Length:710
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 13 Mar 2016 17:29:36 GMT
Location:http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/next-web/rest/orders/60985
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

**General**
Request URL:http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/next-web/rest/orders
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 Created
Remote Address:140.172.184.1:80
```